# Leibniz's theory of subtance and causal interaction - with God

Tags: ontology, causation, rationalism, leibniz

It follows from Leibniz' complete concept theory of truth that substances have no causal interaction with another. But Leibniz also says that created substances depend on God and that God conserves them continuously. Does this conservation involve some sort of causal interaction? If yes, how does that not contradict the first sentence? If no, then how is it that God conserves created substance if not via some causal mechanism?

Comment: On Leibniz's theory, *created* substances cannot causally interact:"*There is… no way in which it could make sense for a monad to be altered or changed internally by any other created thing*". God is not a created substance:"*God gives always to the creature and produces continually all that in it is positive, good and perfect, every perfect gift coming from the Father of lights.*" See [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz-causation/#InteCaus).

Comment: You've arrived at a critical understanding necessary to understand Leibniz who was a devoted Christian and liked and used some East philosophies and mysticism. Your question could be explained using East philosophy's [two truths doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_truths_doctrine).